# check database connection using background worker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I already banging my head with this problem, I use `backgroundWorker` to check if database is **`OPEN`** and here's my code for that:

```
Public Class Form1

    Delegate Sub SetLabelText_Delegate(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)

    Dim sqlconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & My.Settings.Server & ";Initial Catalog=" & My.Settings.Database & ";Integrated Security=false;user id=" & My.Settings.Username & ";password=" & My.Settings.Password & ";Connection Timeout=5;")

    Dim connectionStatus As String

    Private Sub SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)
        If [Label].InvokeRequired Then
            Dim MyDelegate As New SetLabelText_Delegate(AddressOf SetLabelText_ThreadSafe)
            Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[Label], [text]})
        Else
            [Label].Text = [text]
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'I store my database information to my.settings then display it on textboxes for manipulation
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Server
        TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Database
        TextBox3.Text = My.Settings.Username
        TextBox4.Text = My.Settings.Password

        'just getting my computer name
        lblCompName.Text = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        Try

            If sqlconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                sqlconnection.Open()
                connectionStatus = "Online"
                'sqlconnection.Open()
                SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.Label1, "Database Status: online")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            connectionStatus = "Offline"
            sqlconnection.Close()
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.Label1, "Database Status: offline")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            Label1.Text = "Database Status: " & connectionStatus
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Database Status: " & connectionStatus
        End If
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
end class
```

In my code above it does actually works, it does display **"`database is online/offline`"** when restarting my program within the visual studio but when I run the program then turn-off/disable my network connection(my database is on other computer) it always display **`"Database is ONLINE"`** but I'm pretty sure that there is already no connection between my pc and database(because I `PING` it) so it must be display as **`"Database is oFFLINE"`**.

Did I missed something regarding of using **`backgroundWOrker`**? Oh BTW, I'm new in using **`BackgroundWorker`**.
Any help or alternative solutions is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: What happens if instead of using `sqlconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed` you try a `SELECT ...` query and see if that gives you an error?

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago, but can't remember exactly what the issue was, but checking the connection state didn't give reliable results as I recall...

Comment: ohh. ok sir I will try your suggestion. anyways thank you!.